# How to decide what image resolutions to provide for UIImageViews in Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a project that I started in Xcode 7 with multiple UIImageViews,
And in Xcode 7, when using the 600x600 storyboard, if I were to make an UIImageView that were 100x100, it would require an image of 100x100px for x1 and 200x200px for x2 and 300x300px for x3.

However, In Xcode8, there are no 600x600 storyboards.
So, my UIImageView might be 100x100 for an iPhone 7 but 120x120 for a iPhone 7+.
 And many other dimensions for other devices.
How can we decide what what resolution images we need to provide for x1, x2 and x3 under this new system?

Comment: You should be using the `UITraitCollection` and `UITraitEnvironment` apis.

Comment: Nothing has changed, you still use the same densities for each device.

Comment: @JamesP If I create a image view of 100x100 in Xcode 7. Then convert it to Xcode 8, it will be 92x92 for iPhone 7 and 122x122 for iPhone 7+ (Not actual figures). My question is if I make a view in Xcode 8, how do I know that it is meant to be 100x100?

Comment: Just constrain the width and height to 100x100 if you want it to be the same on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can always put constraints for width and height. It is dependant on your design, if you need flexible image then I would suggest get largest one and they will work just fine when you resize it to smaller values.

However, in most cases you want image to be consistent through devices so wiring constraints for height and width would work on all devices as it would be the same size.